# Is it possible to maintain insertion order at global level across partitions in a kakfa topic

Tags: apache-kafka

Im looking at the possibility of using kafka topics and partitions which maintains insertion order across partitions of  a Topic. I have read that order is maintained at only partition level so is there any way to support global ordering

Comment: what is your use case for this  ? You can use one partition

Answer (score 1):

Guaranteed ordering is per-topic-per-partition only. Generally if you define your partition keys according to your processing requirements for strict ordering this is not a problem.

Comment: Basically i have to process the time based events in the  insertion order like there is create event and then there is an update event so i would always like to process update after create only . Now if i choose to have 2 partitions and each event going in P1 and P2 ..then the two consumer C1 and C2 reading the events simultaneously will cause problem. One approach could be then route all the request of same resource(resourceId) to same partition

Comment: @invincible yes - unless every single event must be in strict order (in which case you need one and only one partition) then partition key based on what events must be grouped by - customer id, resource id, etc